# How to prevent price.phtml to be cached (updated prices do not show on category listing; well on product page)

Tags: cache, magento-1.9.3.8

When adjusting the prices for products, as well as the special prices, I have to refresh the block html cache since it turns invalidated, plus the fact that I have to reindex in order to see the updated prices in the category listing page.

The calling to these processes is stored in price.phtml, so I was wondering if there is a possibility for not allowing that content to be cached. The updated prices show well in the product pages, but not in the category page.

Comment: Caching itself is not to blame here. Updates in prices require re-indexing before going to caching system, and IT IS NOT CALLED from price.phtml file. How much frequent do you have these price updates ? If default cron job is in place, it should be doing the re-indexing part for you.

Comment: Prices are updated every 5 min